# Does a connected $F_k$-free graph of order $n$ with the maximum singless Laplacian spectral radius belong to $Ex(n,F_k)$?

Tags: extremal-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected $F_k$-free graph of order $n$ with the maximum singless Laplacian spectral radius. Is $G\in Ex(n,F_k)$?

Here, $Ex(n,H)$ denotes the set of $H$-free graphs of order $n$ with $ex(n,H)$ edges.

Comment: If $G$ is connected, the spectral radius increases if an edge is added, so $G\in Ex(n,F_k)$. A disconnected $G$ it can have the same spectral radius, such as two disjoint copies of a graph in $Ex(n,F_k)$. That may or may not be in $Ex(n,F_k)$ depending on what $F_k$ is (you didn't say).

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thank you so much for the comment. Why the spectral radius increases if an edge is added?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay $F_k$ denotes the $k$-fan graph consisting of $k$ triangles which intersect in exactly one common vertex.

Comment: For any connected graph, let $L$ be the signless Laplacian.  It is non-negative irreducible so the eigenvector $x$ corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $L$ has strictly positive entries. So when adding an edge $\|Lx\|$ becomes larger than before.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks a lot for your explanation. Could you please introduce me a reference about your comment?

Comment: Look up Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I looked up Perron-Frobenius Theorem. But I don't understand properly that why the spectral radius increases if an edge is added. As you told, $L$ is non-negative irreducible. So by the theorem the eigenvector $x$ corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue $r$ of $L$ has strictly positive entries. Now if we assume that $L'$ obtained from $L$ by adding an edge, Now how can I conclude that $r'>r$, where $r'$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $L'$?

Comment: The largest eigenvalue is the largest value of $\|Lx\|$ for vectors $x$ with length 1 and this is achieved when $x$ is the eigenvector. Since $L'$ is the same as $L$ except some entries are increased, $\|L'x\|>\|Lx\|$. So the largest eigenvalue of $L'$ is greater.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I understood completely. Thank you very much for your exact explanation and the time you've spent to me.